# Generating random numbers in numpy with strict lower bounds

Tags: python, numpy, random

So according to numpy's documentation here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html, they say that the random values generated belong to the set [lower, upper) i.e. all values are >= lower, and less than upper. Is there any way to make this a stricter bound, i.e. all values are > lower? I have a particular case in which I want to ensure that all random values lie between 0 and k, but should not be equal to 0, as that will cause my program to crash. Any workarounds/other libraries which can help me?

Comment: how about you call with argument `lower - 1`

Comment: Fun fact: the probability of generating a number **equal** to *lower* is almost 0. Think of how many are the real number that your machine's precision can *fit* inside the `[lower, upper)` range and calculate the reciprocate of that (`1/x`).

Comment: @Krishna That might generate number inside the `(lower - 1, lower)` range.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis as in `(lower-1, upper)`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis It is not almost 0. It is in fact zero: http://stattrek.com/probability-distributions/discrete-continuous.aspx?Tutorial=Stat

Comment: I am not concerned with the probability, but like, if I am iterating over my code, using random values, if it becomes = or < than 0, the code stops mid-iteration. I don't want to leave it to chance for that to happen. At the moment, I am using lower bound as 0.000000001, but, if there is any workaround present, I would prefer to use that.

Comment: @BaileyParker: That's only ideally. These are pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: Can you use `try ... except`?

Comment: @BillBell Yeah actually I am wrong. That's only true for a continuous space of which floating point numbers are not a member.

Comment: @BaileyParker the link I have posted states otherwise

Comment: @VSA I understand your concern but you have better chances discovering you have a distant uncle in south africa that recently passed and left you a surmountable fortune.

Comment: @BaileyParker: It's getting so you can't trust anybody. :-)

Comment: @BillBell Well if you assume that the space of humans is continuous, then isn't the probability that you can trust one 0? ;)

Comment: We'd need to see your code, eh. Another thought: If the random number is sufficiently close to zero some functions will blow up; the number need not be exactly zero. (Can't write more: appointment.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chance of actually getting 0 from a call to `np.ranodm.uniform(0,k)` is practially zero.  If you want to guarantee it, you can set a lower value that is very small.

```
epsilon = np.finfo(np.float).eps
np.random.uniform(epsilon, k)
```

**Edit:**

For my machine, `epsilon` is `2.2204460492503131e-16`.  The chance of getting any *specific* number should be roughly `1 / (1/epsilon)`, or `1 / 4503599627370496`.

As an example, the following code checks for `0.0` occurring in a million length array of `np.random.normal(0,1)`:

```
counter = 0
stop = False
while not stop:
    x = np.random.normal(0,1, size=1000000)
    stop = any(x==0.0)
    counter += 1
    print('\rIteration: {}   '.format(counter), end='')
```

I am currently over 75,000 iteration without a zero occurring.  This is not a perfect test, clearly, but it does demonstrate the minute chance of actually getting a zero.

Comment: `epsilon = np.finfo(np.float).eps` is IMHO cleaner than hardcoding it.

Comment: @SvetlinMladenov, thank you.  I did not know of that.  Updating.

Comment: `1 / 4503599627370496` is winning the classic lotto game of 6/49 **twice in a row**.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to ensure that all random values lie between 0 and k, but should not be equal to 0

If you have numbers in the range `low <= u < high` you can easily convert them to `low < r <= high`:

```
r = high - np.random.uniform(0, high - low)
```

Of course this is only useful if `r` is allowed to include `high` but not `low`.